# XSD file for custom labels

Tags: xml, customlabel, continuous-integration

I'm trying to generate an XSD for the customlabels.xml file. The idea is to generate this file and validate the custom labels file as part of the pipeline so that errors can be detected early on.

The sample custom labels file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomLabels xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <labels>
        <fullName>Label1</fullName>
        <categories>L1</categories>
        <language>en_US</language>
        <protected>false</protected>
        <shortDescription>This is label 1</shortDescription>
        <value>1</value>
    </labels>
    <labels>
        <fullName>Label2</fullName>
        <categories>L2</categories>
        <language>en_US</language>
        <protected>false</protected>
        <shortDescription>Label 2 </shortDescription>
        <value>2</value>
    </labels>
</CustomLabels>
```

The xsd I've generated so far is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"
           targetNamespace="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

  <xs:element name="CustomLabels">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="labels">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="fullName" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="categories" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element name="language" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="protected" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element name="shortDescription" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I'm stuck on the final step, that is putting an **uniqueness** check on the fullName. I can't seem to figure out how to put this enforcement. Can anyone help out?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you can find details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717515/unique-constraint-in-xml-schema) that should give you the answer you need.

Comment: @PhilW, thanks for pointing me to that document. Would you be able to describe how I can use that document to enforce a uniqueness constraig on a complex inner type?

Comment: You define the unique constraint within the root node and define an XPath that references the required value. Here, that is just `labels/fullName` and `.`.

Comment: @PhilW If you're talking about something like below at the bottom, unfortunatly I already attempted this, but did not work --> </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="fullname_unique">
            <xs:selector xpath="labels/fullName"/>
            <xs:field xpath="."/>
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>

Comment: Have you tried a path of `//labels/fullName` and/or a field of `./text()`. I don't have access to a computer to give you a tested answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the fact that the elements are in a namespace and the XPath expressions need to reflect this. Hence adding <xs:selector xpath="p:labels/p:fullName"/> and add xmlns:p="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" to the xs:schema element fixed the issue. The final XSD looked like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"
           xmlns:p="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"
           targetNamespace="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

  <xs:element name="CustomLabels">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="labels">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="fullName" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="categories" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element name="language" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="protected" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element name="shortDescription" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="fullname_unique">
            <xs:selector xpath="p:labels/p:fullName"/>
            <xs:field xpath="."/>
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Glad you sorted it for yourself, and posted a self-answer. Thanks!